# How to create new @ngrx files using CLI in angular 5 application?

Tags: rxjs, angular5, ngrx

Currently I'm working on the angular 5 application, I want to create @ngrx/effects, actions, reducers, store, state ts files also the spec.ts files using command prompt(window cli), like component creation in angular cli(ng g c 'componentname')
ex: ng g effect 'filename'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They specifically created a module for this:

see https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/schematics

Answer (score 2):

You will need third party software to handle this, or you can write your own shell/node scripts. Check out Nrwl: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples#ngrx-store-generation

Comment: any example u can shre of sample node scripts